# How to render custom 3d object in react native

Tags: react-native, three.js, 3d, expo

I've managed to configure 3d rendering of a red cube in react native using Three.js expo-three and expo-gl,
But I want to let the user render their own custom 3d objects that they might have (.obj or .mtl extensions) but I'm not sure how to let them load them.

This is the code I have for the cube rendering:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { GLView } from 'expo-gl';
//@ts-ignore
import * as THREE from "three";
import ExpoTHREE, { Renderer } from "expo-three"

interface Props {
    route: any
}

const Player: React.FC<Props> = ({ route }) => {
    const { item } = route.params;

    const onContextCreate = async (gl: any) => {
        // 1. Scene
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        // 2. Camera
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, gl.drawingBufferWidth / gl.drawingBufferHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        gl.canvas = { width: gl.drawingBufferWidth, height: gl.drawingBufferHeight }
        camera.position.z = 1.5

        const renderer = new Renderer({ gl })
        renderer.setSize(gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight)

        const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'red' })

        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        scene.add(cube)

        const render = () => {
            requestAnimationFrame(render)
            cube.rotation.x += 0.1
            cube.rotation.y += 0.1
            renderer.render(scene, camera)
            gl.endFrameEXP()
        }

        render()
    };


    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <GLView
                style={{ width: '90%', height: '90%', }}
                onContextCreate={onContextCreate}
            />
        </View>
    )
}


export default Player
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader

Comment: Is there a way to load 3d object from a url and not a path?